# Task continuation to maintain UI thread responsiveness

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm using Tasks in WinForms to remove expensive methods from my UI thread.  In my updateComplete and updateFailed tasks, I have to set _updateMessageTaskInProgress to false and enable my controls.  Is there any way I can do this in a separate task which either updateComplete or updateFailed continues too once either is complete (as I currently have duplicate code)?  Plus, is there a better way of implementing _updateMessageTaskInProgress - I don't want more than one task to run at the same time.

```
private void PerformUpdate()
{
    if (!_updateMessageTaskInProgress)
        {
            LoadButton.Enabled = false;
            MonthEndDateEdit.Enabled = false;
            BankIssuerListEdit.Enabled = false;

            Task updateMessages = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                _updateMessageTaskInProgress = true;

                ExpensiveMethod();
            });

            // Task runs when updateMessages completes without exception.  Runs on UI thread.
            Task updateComplete = updateMessages.ContinueWith(update =>
            {
                DoSuccessfulStuff();

                _updateMessageTaskInProgress = false;
                LoadButton.Enabled = true;
                MonthEndDateEdit.Enabled = true;
                BankIssuerListEdit.Enabled = true;
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            // Task runs when updateMessages completes with exception.  Runs on UI thread.
            Task updateFailed = updateMessages.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                DoFailureStuff();

                _updateMessageTaskInProgress = false;
                LoadButton.Enabled = true;
                MonthEndDateEdit.Enabled = true;
                BankIssuerListEdit.Enabled = true;
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
}
```

Comment: Your `_updateMessageTaskInProgress` has a race condition: it's possible that two tasks will run at the same time, if both start at about the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Event Based Asynchronous-**TYPE** Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) for this. A simplified version of the code I use to spin-off method onto a background thread using TPL is below

```
private void TaskSpin(TaskScheduler uiScheduler, 
                      Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool> asyncMethod, 
                      object[] methodParameters)
{
    try
    {
        Task asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => 
            asyncMethod(uiScheduler, methodParameters));

        // Callback for finish/cancellation.
        asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
        {
            // Check task status.
            switch (task.Status)
            {
                // Handle any exceptions to prevent UnobservedTaskException.             
                case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
                    if (asyncTask.Result)
                        UpdateUI(uiScheduler, "OK");
                    else
                    {
                        string strErrComplete = "Process failed.";
                        UpdateUI(uiScheduler, strErrComplete);
                    }
                    break;
                case TaskStatus.Faulted:
                    string strFatalErr = String.Empty;
                    UpdateUI(uiScheduler, "Fatal Error);
                    if (task.Exception != null)
                        strFatalErr = task.Exception.InnerException.Message;
                    else
                        strFatalErr = "Operation failed";
                    MessageBox.Show(strFatalErr);
                    break;
            }
            asyncTask.Dispose();
            return;
        }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        Utils.ErrMsg(eX.Message);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

*Edit. Note, in the above `uiScheduler` is the `TaskScheduler` for the UI Thread. That is*

```
TaskSheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
```

Comment: So many questions: How is this EAP? (I don't see any events in your code.) What is the point of having `asyncTask` as a parameter that's never used? Why does `asyncMethod` take a `TaskScheduler` as a parameter?

Comment: It is EAP - here the `task.ContinueWith` is our event. The continuation performs the work that would typically be performed by the AsyncCallback delegate. It is invoked when the antecedent completes, and the data buffer has been filled. `asyncTask` is used, it is passed into the method for MY purposes (I state in the question that this is a trimmed version of some code I have - perhaps I should do some more trimming :]). Finally, the `uiScheduler` is passed into the method so that within that method you can update the UI thread.

Comment: This really isn't EAP. EAP actually uses events, like [`WebClient.DownloadFileCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted.aspx). `ContinueWith` is no event, that's a method that you pass a delegate into.

Comment: The link I provided - to MSDN suggests the opposit... EAP is essentailly any thing that provide a number of facilities to a multi-threaded implementation (is it not?). Although for TPL this can take many guises I thought this was one of them based on what is stated [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) in the documentation. You point is taken...

Comment: If you read the second bullet in the doc you linked, it describes exactly what EAP looks like: a method and a `Completed` event. Anything else is not EAP.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just extract a method?

```
    private void SetLock(bool lock)
    {
        LoadButton.Enabled = !lock;
        MonthEndDateEdit.Enabled = !lock;
        BankIssuerListEdit.Enabled = !lock;
        _updateMessageTaskInProgress = lock;
    }

    private void PerformUpdate()
    {
        if (!_updateMessageTaskInProgress)
        {
            SetLock(true);
            Task updateMessages = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                ExpensiveMethod();
            });

            // Task runs when updateMessages completes without exception.  Runs on UI thread.
            Task updateComplete = updateMessages.ContinueWith(update =>
            {
                DoSuccessfulStuff();
                SetLock(false);
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

            // Task runs when updateMessages completes with exception.  Runs on UI thread.
            Task updateFailed = updateMessages.ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                DoFailureStuff();
                SetLock(false);
            }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You must access task.Exception in your failed handler to avoid an exception from the task finalizer